# How do I check the page name in an if statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two pages (default.aspx and view.aspx) and want to add a class to an anchor tag depending on page name. The code would be something like the following, but I'm not sure what to put for the condition part of the if statement when I have pagename="default.aspx".

```
<li><a href="make.aspx" <% if(pagename="default.aspx") { %>class="open"<% } %>><i class="icon-comment-alt"></i> Make Request</a>
<li><a href="view=.aspx" <% if(pagename="view.aspx") { %>class="open"<% } %>>><i class="icon-folder-open-alt"></i> View Requests</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%
    string pagename = new FileInfo(this.Request.Url.LocalPath).Name;
%>
```

Something like this preceding the `if` statements in each page should generally work.

I wouldn't recommend using a lot of inline C# code in your markup files with maintainability and separation of concerns in mind, but it can work.

For more information and qualifications on getting the current page name as outlined above, check out a [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3594353/1810429).

Comment: So doing this on the code behind file is better? Just add the class attribute to the anchor?

Comment: Yes, I think so - certainly getting the page's name.  It just separates behavior from presentation and avoids confusion where the two are intertwined in the markup file.

Comment: Yep got it to work with: string pagename = new System.IO.FileInfo(this.Request.Url.LocalPath).Name; thanks!

Comment: <% if(pagename=="default.aspx") { %>class="open"<% } %>